# Heroku ENV Vars returned undefined yet it is defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

So I have an app that utilizes both Google Map API and Yelp API.

In order to hide my API keys from the public, I made a `config.js` files that holds the information without me uploading to github.

I've also made ENV Vars to all of the API keys that are included in my `config.js`

However, I am getting an undefined variable for `googleAPI`:

```
const googleAPI = process.env.GOOGLEAPI || require('../../../src/server/config').googleAPI;
```

I type `heroku config` to make sure the ENV Var is set and I am seeing it that it is defined:

```
GOOGLEAPI:             dfkslfskdsMyAPIKeyslsjflksjdflksd
```

My Yelp aspect seems to be working with no problem, but only `googleAPI` is returning me `undefined`, even though its ENV Var is set.

I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new file named `.env` in your project's root directory.
2. Add all the config vars you want to use locally to the file in this format: `GOOGLEAPI=dfkslfskdsMyAPIKeyslsjflksjdflksd`.
3. run `heroku local` in terminal.

For more information:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

Answer (score 0):

In my `.gitignore` file, I added env. So Heroku doesn't find the variables from the env file. If anyone does not want to add the env file in git he can add configurations as `config vars` in Heroku project settings.